# how to evaluate $0$ times infinity

Tags: integration, self-learning

I am trying to evaluate this expression (derived from integration)

$[\frac{1}{a}e^{-ax} -\frac{1}{a^2}e^{-ax}]$ between infinity and zero

I get $\frac{1}{a^2}$, but I am assuming that the first term evaluated at infinity is $0$.

Is this assumption correct, i.e. can we say $0$ times infinity $= 0$?

(Some web sites state that this is indeterminate;  if so, I am not sure how to apply an "indeterminate" term to the integral).

Comment: Limits. Limits is how to apply an indeterminate term to an integral.

Comment: Usually you solve the integral first using some limit variable and then you take the limit as this variable approaches infinity afterwards. Expressions of the type $0 \cdot \infty$ can be rearanged to an expression of the form $\frac{0}{0}$, which may be evaluated using L’Hôpital’s rule.

Comment: Are you evaluating $x$ as $0$ and $\infty$? I don't see anywhere that you would multiply $0\cdot \infty$ in doing that, unless $a$ is also $0$ or $\infty$. And that case, this would not be the correct integration result.